# Spyder (4.1.5) Code Cell Function Change Highlight Appearance

Tags: python, spyder

The Code Cell function in Sypder is an amazing tool that can divide up a script into blocks which can be executed separately. When a cell block is selected it is also highlighted in a solid colour to assist with readability. The image below is taken from [Syder](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/editor.html).

[image: Code Cell Usage and Highlighting]

However, on my editor the highlights are applied to each line with a thin gap in between (refer to image below).

[image: Spyder 4.1.5 Code Cell Highlight Applied to Each Line.]

This appearance makes the workspace look more cluttered and distracting. I would like to change it to a solid colour as shown on Spyder's webpage. I cannot seem to find an option to change the appearance inside Spyder's settings and a search online does not yield any answers either.

I wanted to ask how can I change the highlighting appearance from stripes to a solid colour?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Are you using macOS and a retina display monitor?

Comment: No, I am using a Surface Pro 4. In fact I do not seem to have this issue when using Spyder on my desktop computer. Could this be an issue with the Surface Pro 4?

Comment: No, I think it's related to high resolution screens. What's your screen resolution?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I have this too! Not on the default font size, but if I change it to 11 or 12, I do. This is on a 2560x1440 resolution with scaling enabled to 125% in Windows. If I set scaling on 100%, indeed the gaps are gone.